# PHP - Combining recent posts with recent work

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

i'm trying to pull in 2 seperate feeds onto my wordpress homepage (recent portfolio work & recent blog posts). I want both sets to sit within the same ul. I've managed to pull in the portfolio feed, but i'm having trouble with the blog feed.

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => 4 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >';
                echo '<div class="recent-thumb">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="recent-title"><span>'; the_title(); echo '</span></div>';
            echo '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
    ?>

    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page'=> 4 );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >';
            echo '<div class="home-blog-category">'; user_the_categories(); echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="home-blog-title">'; the_title(); echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="home-blog-excerpt">'; echo excerpt(27); echo '</div>';
            echo '<span class="home-blog-plus"><span class="home-blog-plus-wrap"><span class="horizontal"></span><span class="vertical"></span></span></span>';
        echo '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help with getting the post feed to pull? I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way of doing it, so if anyone has a better way of combining the two, that would also be appreciated! My knowledge of PHP is very limited :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use **array_combine** function in php to combine two results( **$the_query & $loop** ) and use a single while loop.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_combine.asp

Comment: Ok, but my 'post' array is not working, do you know why?

Comment: use **wp_reset_query()** before new WP_Query( $args ); https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query